# Default_random_engine passed into a function gives repeatable results

Tags: c++, c++11, random, shuffle

I have a class `Permutation` that inherits from `std::vector<int>`. I created a constructor that makes the object filled with non-repeating numbers. Randomness is meant to be guaranteed by `<random>` stuff, so the declaration goes like this:

```
/* Creates a random permutation of a given length
 * Input: n - length of permutation
 *        generator - engine that does the randomizing work */
Permutation(int n, default_random_engine generator);
```

Function itself looks like this (irrevelant details skipped):

```
Permutation::Permutation(int n, default_random_engine generator):
vector<int>(n, 0)
{
    vector<int> someIntermediateStep(n, 0);
    iota(someIntermediateStep.begin(), someIntermediateStep.end(), 0); //0, 1, 2...

    shuffle(someIntermediateStep.begin(), someIntermediateStep.end(), 
            generator);

    // etc.
 }
```

And is called in the following context:

```
auto seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
static std::default_random_engine generator(seed);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    Permutation test(length, generator);
```

Code compiles perfectly fine, but all instances of `Permutation` are the same. How to force regular generation of random numbers? I know that `default_random_engine` should be binded to a distribution object, but hey, I don't have any – I use the engine only in `shuffle()` (at least at the moment).

Is there any solution or a workaround that still uses the goodness of `<random>`?

Comment: Did you try passing the engine to the `Permutation` constructor by reference?

Comment: why is `generator` defined as static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Permutation` constructor takes the engine in by value. So, in this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    Permutation test(length, generator);
```

You are passing a copy of the same engine, in the same state, over and over. So you are of course getting the same results. Pass the engine by reference instead

```
Permutation::Permutation(int n, default_random_engine& generator)
```

That way its state will be modified by the call to `std::shuffle`.

Answer (score 0):

So a childish mistake, just as I supposed – I mixed various solutions to similar problems in a wrong way.

As Benjamin pointed out, I mustn't copy the same engine over and over again, because it remains, well, the same. But this alone doesn't solve the issue, since the engine is pointlessly declared `static` (thanks, Zereges).

For the sake of clarity, corrected code looks like this:

```
Permutation(int n, default_random_engine &generator);

// [...]

Permutation::Permutation(int n, default_random_engine generator):
vector<int>(n, 0)
{
    vector<int> someIntermediateStep(n, 0);
    iota(someIntermediateStep.begin(), someIntermediateStep.end(), 0); //0, 1, 2...

    shuffle(someIntermediateStep.begin(), someIntermediateStep.end(), 
        generator);

    // etc.
}

// [...]
// some function
auto seed = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
default_random_engine generator(seed);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    Permutation test(length, generator);
```